# Is there any way to change a .NET URL display property in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

OK, I've looked all over for this answer, and although I have found answers that sort of answer the question, I couldn't find an exact answer to my question:

I have code in .NET that takes information and essentially creates a string, which is a URL to a PDF file in a gridview. Here is some of the code in question:

```
<a href='<# string.Concat("folder/", (Eval("user_account)), "/", (Eval("name")), ".pdf' target='_blank")%>'>
```

I know for a fact this code works. I've tested it, and it displays the PDFs the way it is supposed to. My question is: Is there a way to somehow switch this "off" so to speak? I am trying to turn off the hyperlink part so it won't direct the user to anything if they click it, but only in certain cases. Below is one case where I don't want it to display the hyperlink. This code is located in the RowDataBound method:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
if (Message.ToString() == "Flag")
{
lblError.Text = "Testing error message.";
//What else needs to go here to not display the URL under these conditions?
}
}
```

I also tested this code, and it displays the label error message when one of the PDFs in the database has this flag set to "Flag". But along with this code, I also need the PDF to not display or have the hyperlink available. I am not sure if this is possible, or if there is a better solution.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Either do not create the hyperlink or set it to an empty string in those cases. Have you tried that?

Comment: You could turn that into a LinkButton, validate that on the server, and then redirect to the PDF

Comment: @CodingYoshi I haven't thought of that. But is there a way to change the hyperlink for the .NET side to an empty string via the C# side?

Comment: There is an asp hyperlink server control.

Answer (score 0):

try to add to your html page this `id="linkid" runat="server"`:

```
<a id="linkid" runat="server" href='<# string.Concat("folder/", (Eval("user_account)), "/", (Eval("name")), ".pdf' target='_blank")%>'>
```

then at your `Code Behind`

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
if (Message.ToString() == "Flag")
{
lblError.Text = "Testing error message.";
//What else needs to go here to not display the URL under these conditions?
  linkid.Visible = false;
}
}
```

Assuming that you have a control Dropdown control in your Grid in a loop.

```
DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)gridid.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("drpcontrolid");
 drp.Visible = false
```

Comment: the first part may work. But I don't have a dropdown list

Comment: Yeah, it is just an example on how to manage a control working with grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can access almost anything in the gridview in your code behind but you need to get a reference to it first.

One way would be to reference the cell in the gridview directly. Cells are numbered in the order they are added to the gridview starting with 0. So, assuming your cell is the 9th one in your datarow...

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    e.Row.Cells[8].Text = "......"
}
```

One you have the reference to the cell you can do pretty much anything you want to with it. You can add, remove, append text to it using the .Text property. You can also add controls to it using the .Controls collection.

Comment: that is pretty simple. But for the .Controls collection, or any collection, is there  a way to just simply remove the link, but keep everything else? I still want the text to be the same, just want to remove the link.

Comment: Absolutely. You need to get a reference to the control and then remove it.

Comment: It would be easier if you made your link a HyperLink or some other server control. Take a look at @reds answer for the method to find a control. Assuming you change your link to a HyperLink: HyperLink h = (HyperLink)gridid.rows[i].cells[1].FindControl("myhyperlink"); if (h != null) gridid.rows[i].cells[1].Cont5rols.Remove(h);